# Solution of the Following System of Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to solve the following system of differential equations $$x'-5x+y+4z=0 ,\space y'+12x-5y-12z=0 , \space z'-10x+3y+9z=0$$ The general solution I found was: $$X=C_1\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{matrix}\right) e^t + C_2\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right) e^t +C_3 \left(\begin{matrix} 1\\-2\\2 \end{matrix}\right)e^{-t}$$

Is it correct??

Comment: The middle term looks suspicious... since it could be discarded something is probably wrong with the algebra.

Comment: @Gregory so can you give me the solution ?

Comment: If you could show your work, I can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: @Gregory You can check my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check correctness of your solution, as you can do by direct verification. But I tell you the systematic and simple way to solve such systems. Define

$$ X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then you have a matrix differential equation as
$$ \frac{dX}{dt} = M.X $$
for the square matrix $M$ containing constant coefficients. Assume that $X_0$ denote initial conditions, then the solution is
$$X = \exp[tM].X_0$$
The exponential of matrix is often simplified by calculating some first terms of its Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do it like this:
First I calculated the Eigen Values which are $1,1,-1$. As two of them are repeating: $$(A-\lambda_1 I)X =\left(\begin{matrix} 4&-1&-4\\-12&4&12\\10&-3&-10 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} x\\y\\z \end{matrix}\right)=0 $$
After reducing, I got $x=z \space, \space y=0\space Let\space z=k_1 \rightarrow x=k_1, \space y=k_2=0$ Now, $$\left(\begin{matrix} z\\y\\z \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} k_1\\0\\k_1 \end{matrix}\right)=k_1\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{matrix}\right)+k_2 \left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right)$$ 
so eigen vectors in this case are $\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{matrix}\right) and \left(\begin{matrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: Your matrix is incorrect.

Comment: @Paichu How??????

Comment: $A =\left(\begin{matrix} 5 & -1 & -4 \\ -12 & 5 & 12 \\ 10 & -3 & -9 \end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: EDIT: @Paichu got it right the first time, unlike me so I removed my quick attempt.

Comment: @Paichu The matrix I wrote is not A. Its is $(A-\lambda_1 I)$